# What is source references in MISRA C?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, misra, unspecified-behavior, implementation-defined-behavior

In the MISRA C document there are explanations about "Source References" and there is a table whose rows are:
Unspecified, Undefined, Implementation-defined, Locale-specific, MISRA Guidelines, K&R, Koenig and IEC 61508 and introduces these as source reference. I have researched about Unspecified, Undefined, Implementation-defined, and Locale-specific behaviors. I have become somewhat familiar with them. But I don't know the concept of Source reference and why these behaviors are mentioned in Source references. Also some MISRA C rules that have Source reference. What does this mean?
Thanks.

Comment: What is MISRA and how to cook it: https://pvs-studio.com/en/blog/posts/cpp/0702/

Answer (score 1):

The source references are the primary sources that are MISRA's justifications for the Guidelines, as explained in section 6.10 of MISRA C:

> Where a guideline originates from one or more published sources these
> are indicated in square brackets after the guideline. This serves two
> purposes. Firstly the specific sources may be consulted by a reader
> wishing to gain a fuller understanding of the rationale behind the
> guideline (for example when considering a request for a deviation).
> Secondly, with regard to Portability Issues described in The Standard,
> the form of the source gives extra information about the nature of the
> problem.
>
> Rules which do not have a source reference may have
> originated from a contributing company’s in-house standard, or have
> been suggested by a reviewer, or be widely accepted good practice.

These source references fall into two categories, :

1. Those internal to the C standard
2. Other

Those internal to the C standard (enumerated in Appendix J of the C Standard) cover:

1. Undefined behaviour
2. Unspecified behaviour
3. Implementation defined behaviour
4. Locale-specific behaviour

Those external to the C standard include various Standards (eg IEC 61508) or other well-respected books

-- see profile for affiliation

Comment: In the world of technical standards bureaucracy, it's a bit confusing that 6.10 points to Annex J of the standard, which is _informative_ and not normative. So it shouldn't be used as source. A more correct source would be to give the normative chapter that Annex J points to, directly in the MISRA rule. Also Annex J is only a summary of what's explicitly explicitly listed as poorly-defined behavior in the standard. There are many common bugs which are implicitly UB - where one might be able to provide a source in the normative chapters but find one inside Annex J.

Comment: The whole topic of identifying IDB/USB/UDB in the C standard is a long one.  We use Appendix J because it is easier to show coverage of that list, rather than paragraphs across the standard!  The next C standard should, at least, have numbered rather than un-numbered bullets...

Comment: And of course, in that world of technical standards bureaucracy, MISRA C is not a Standard and therefore the norms of ISO/IEC do not apply

Comment: Well ISO/IEC 9899 is a standard :) Anyway, for someone familiar with the C standard, it doesn't take _that_ much work to dig up the relevant part(s) corresponding to a certain MISRA rule. It will be far harder to find canonical sources for stuff like "don't use recursion". Although since for example Hatton already created the embryo for a safe subset, I'm surprised his book isn't used as source more frequently - for example it comes with a list of severity of all UB (in C90 anyway) similar to what CERT C uses.

Comment: @Lundin: What does C89 require for a blob of source text to be a "Conforming C Program"?  What does it require for something to be a "Conforming C Implementation"?  I wonder how many other "standards" define conformance as loosely as the C Standard does without offering strong recommendations that go far beyond conformance requirements?

Comment: @supercat MISRA C is at least indirectly based on scientific research and domain expertise. C was invented by one dude at AT&T experimenting with what programming language that might suit the equally experimental Unix OS - they were pioneers back in the early 70s and didn't have much in the way of research to base their work on. It's not possible to give a source let alone a rationale for why most things in C were designed the way they were, mainly it just inherited a lot of stuff from even more experimental B and BCPL. Many features simply lack rationale.

Comment: @Lundin: What made C useful in the 1980s is that it wasn't *a* language, but rather a *recipe* for producing language dialects tailored to particular platforms and purposes.  Many actions were expected to have 100% predictable behavior on implementations targeting some platforms, and unpredictable behavior on those targeting others, but people familiar with a platforms would know which actions would be processed predictably.  If the Standard were to recognize a compiler and execution environment as distinct entities, the number of constructs that invoke completely undefined behavior...

Comment: ...at the language level could be slashed.  If an implementation specifies a mapping between language constructs and execution-environment concepts, behavior of many constructs the Standard presently classifies as UB would be defined in cases where the execution environment defines them, and UB in cases where the execution environment doesn't, or where they would cause the execution environment to violate a compiler's documented requirements.

Comment: If the C Standard was a software requirement specification you would send it back, asking for the gaps to be filled.  MISRA is an attempt to protect against those gaps - but it's not perfect.

Comment: @supercat That has nothing to do with the topic of source references in MISRA C.